# How to monitor calls to an external library function?

Tags: ida

I have an application which is executing oci statements using OCIStmtExecute(). I need to know which sql statement is being passed to OCIStmtPrepare on what action. Tried using API Monitor but there weren't OCI.dll functions. Also placing a breakpoint doesn't help since it's executing a notify statement almost every half a second.

Comment: If you use WinDbg, you can set a breakpoint, have it dump out the parameter, then continue execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried using API Monitor but there weren't OCI.dll functions.

OCI.dll most certainly does export functions, including `OCIStmtExecute()` and `OCIStmtPrepare()`:

[image: OCIStmtExecute]

If you're not seeing them in API Monitor, it's because you've not told API Monitor to log them correctly, or because they're not really being called by the target process.

Comment: How do i tell API Monitor to log them ? I'm certain that the application is using those functions.

Comment: You need to use its _External DLL Filter_ functionality.

Comment: I'm checking boxes next to functions but it doesnt help. Do i need to set another filter for them from somewhere ?

Comment: You may want to post your question on API Monitor's web forum: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/forum/1-api-monitor/

Comment: API Monitor worked perfectly. Apparently i wasn't selecting application module while applying filter. Thanks.